# Travel time in elliptical orbit around the sun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Hi I'm calculating a problem, and I think it ought to be correct - but the result I get isn't.

The problem is described as follow:

> A spacecraft is traveling from Earth to Venus in an elliptical, but
>   NON-Hohman transfer orbit, starting at the apocentre at 1 AU. The
>   semi-major axis of this elliptical orbit, a = 0.75 AU. After a few
>   months the orbit of the spacecraft crosses  the orbit of Venus. What
>   is the “exact” travel time to this crossing point in days?

With some numbers (which I used for calculations):
$$\mu_s = 1.33 \cdot 10^{11}$$
$$R_{venus} =  0.72 AU$$
$$1 AU =  150 \cdot 10^6 km$$

From the geometrics (elliptical orbit around the sun) the eccentricity can be calculated:
$$a(1+e) = R_{earth} \rightarrow e = \tfrac{1}{3}$$
This then can give the true anomaly in a straight forward manner (from the range equation for an ellips):
$$r = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos(\theta)}$$
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{R_{venus}} - 1 = \tfrac{25}{27}$$

Now I'm wondering a bit if I actually take the correct angle for theta... In the rest of my calculations I used this value ($\theta = 22.2 ^{\circ}$) as the angle between the sun-apocenter & sun-orbit crossing vectors. (A schematic drawing on paper did make this "seem correct").

Now from this (and using simple schematic drawing/geometry) the following can be said (to get the eccentric anomaly):
$$R_{venus} \cos(\theta)  - ae = a \cos(E)$$
$$E = 0.9818 rad$$
Now the time can be calculated using [kepler's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_Equation) as following:
$$E - e\sin(E) = M = n(t - t_p)$$
$$n = \sqrt{\frac{\mu_{sun}}{a^3}} = 3.05 \cdot 10^{-7} s^{-1}$$
That gives
$$t - t_p = t = 2421311 s = 28 d$$

However this is wrong, apparently the correct result is "72 days". What am I doing wrong? Where did I make mistakes?

Comment: Check your calculation for $\cos{\theta}$.You forgot to divide by $e$.